# Adding authorization to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, authorization

I cannot seem to find a good example for this. I have for example, a `TicketController`

I define a ticket resource in my routes.rb.

You only need to be logged in as a customer to GET a ticket, but you must be logged in as an administrator to PUT a ticket.

I currently do this at the controller level. I have a before_action for certain controller methods that check if you are logged in as customer or admin.

I'm wondering what the correct way to do this is. I would think ideally I could require certain authorization for specific actions on a specific resource. For example, the ticket resource GET action only needs to be logged in as a customer whereas the PUT action can only happen if you are an admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know the gems [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)?

I think they can help you manage authorizations on resources in a single place instead of having to do it in every controller.

Comment: The [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem is also worth looking into. It uses policy classes that define who should be able to perform what actions

Answer (score 0):

Using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem is a common way to manage user authorizations on different resources. You can go through [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) railscast which covers the basics of using this gem.

Note: Cancan gem is however not updated since long, so would recommend using [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), which has similar functionality and syntax, but is actively supported and updated.